# How do I prevent failed to create session error in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am new to tensorflow and Keras, below is my code

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # for reproducibility

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# 5. Preprocess input data
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# 6. Preprocess class labels
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

# 7. Define model architecture
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape= 
(28,28,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# 8. Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# 9. Fit model on training data
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)

# 10. Evaluate model on test data
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

I keep getting the following error after running this code

2018-07-31 19:25:45.099850: I C:\users\nwani_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2018-07-31 19:25:45.711357: I C:\users\nwani_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found
device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 840M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.124
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.66GiB
2018-07-31 19:25:45.718218: I C:\users\nwani_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-31 19:25:45.722718: E C:\users\nwani_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:154] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Seth Siva\Documents\mnist digit recognizer.py", line 44, in 
    batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1042, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2653, in **call**
    if hasattr(get_session(), '_make_callable_from_options'):
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 183, in get_session
    _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1560, in **init**
    super(Session, self).**init**(target, graph, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Seth Siva\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 633, in **init**
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.

Comment: Normally creating session will relate to memory shortage in GPU but I think it's not the case here. Have you tried reinstalling the CUDA?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just tried reinstalling CUDA, and fortunately it worked, thanks a lot.